# How can i make the color of the texture the same as the hand?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I'm trying to make the brown of the texture blend in with the hand but i can't get it right, i also put the same values for the two colors[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll need to pack the resources into the Blend file (File > External Data > Pack Resources and save file) and upload it here again before we can see the image with the ace of spades decal on it. I presume you're talking about the difference between the background colour on the image and the Material.026 colour you're using for the rest of the body? You should be able to just use the eyedropper from the colour palette to copy the colour from the decal in the 3D view into your material Base Color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in colour is actually caused by the differing reflective and anisotropic properties of both the spade and body materials. A quick fix would be to use the **exact** same settings for the skin across both. Your mistake was to use a standard Diffuse shader as a stand in for a Principled BDSF (See the first screenshot).

However copy and pasting the same shader across isn't ideal because if you want to update your skin material later down the line you'll have to update it in multiple places.

To avoid this you can group your skin texture and then instance it in your hand material. That way, any updates you make to your Skin Material will automatically update the spade (see second screenshot).

There are a few approaches you can make to recreating something like this in future. UVMapping and 3D Painting are two techniques that unlock huge potential for customising the look of your models and will add flexibility to your workflow.

[image]

[image]